# Grouping values and changing values which do not allow the rest of the row to group

Tags: sql, postgresql

Not sure how to describe this, but I want to group a row of values, where one field has two or more different values and set the value of that (but concatenating or changing the values) to give just one single row.

For example:
I have a simple table (all fields are Strings) of people next to their departments. But some people belong to more than one department.

```
select department_ind, name 
from jobs
;

department_ind  name
1               Michael
2               Michael
2               Sarah
3               Dave
2               Sally
4               Sally
```

I want to group by name, and concatenate the department_ind. So the results show look like:

```
department_ind  name
1,2             Michael
2               Sarah
3               Dave
2,4             Sally
```

Thanks

Comment: What data type would you like to have for the aggregate? For text types see a_horse_with_no_name's answer...

Comment: all string fields. Edited question to show this.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings? That's bad design choice.

Comment: They aren't, was just using numbers in this example. In reality I am using string values. Should have used a,b,c in the example in hindsight, but I got the answer I was after now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string_agg()`

```
select string_agg(department_ind::text, ',') as departments,
       name
from jobs
group by name;
```